# YouTube API Video Upload Parse Error in C#

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video (resumable) to YouTube via the API in C# (not through client).

I'm following [these instructions on using resumable upload protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)

However when I make the attempt I get back an Parse Error.

Here is my request:

---

```
POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails&key={api_key} HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
X-upload-content-length: 5346742
X-upload-content-type: video/*
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-length: 277
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "My video title",
    "description": "This is a description of my video",
    "tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
    "categoryId": 22
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "embeddable": True,
    "license": "youtube"
  }
}
```

Here is the response:

---

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Alternate-protocol: 443:quic
Content-length: 171
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Sep 30 2013 10:58:35 (1380563915)
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 21:38:10 GMT
Content-type: application/json

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The parse error is due to **True** being written with a big T.

(using the beta library is not an option for me becuase of Unity. .NET 2.0..)

Comment: gulgi, 

I did try your suggestion and it didn't seem to have any effect.

I still get the same response.

    {
    error: {
     errors: [1]
      0:  {
        domain: "global"
        reason: "parseError"
        message: "Parse Error"
       }-
    
      code: 400
      message: "Parse Error"
     }
    }

Comment: S Abraham: The "||" in the title might also be a problem. I have gotten upload to work, apart from when there is "symbols" in title or description.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use Google GData Youtube Api for .NET ?

```
        string developerkey = "developerKey";
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Somethinghere", developerkey, "googleUserName", "googlePassWord");
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

        newVideo.Title = "Video Title Here || ArgeKumandan";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
        newVideo.Description = "My description";
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
        // alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
        // newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");

        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(@"D:\video ArgeKumandan.flv", "video/flv");

        createdVideo  = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Comment: ArgeKumandan, I would prefer to do it without using a beta sdk. Also in the example you gave it requires that I know the username & password. I have a valid OAuth2 token but not username/password. I would use the .NET SDK if there is no way to make the browser approach work.