# 400 Bad request while uploading video to youtube using REST API in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: rest, windows-runtime, youtube-api, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

Below given is my code for uploading video to youtube using REST API in Windows Phone 8.1. I have followed guide from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol). It returns me 400 Bad request with error JSON (which is given after code). Anyone has idea what is wrong in my code?

```csharp
public async Task UploadVideoAsync(Token AuthToken)
{
    string json = @"{
                        ""snippet"": {
                        ""title"": ""using API"",
                        ""description"": ""This is a description of my video"",
                        ""tags"": [""cool"", ""video"", ""more keywords""],
                        ""categoryId"": 21,
                        },
                        ""status"": {
                        ""privacyStatus"": ""public"",
                        ""embeddable"": True,
                        ""license"": ""youtube""
                        }
                    }";

    var JsonReqMsg = new HttpStringContent(json);

    JsonReqMsg.Headers.ContentType = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json") 
    {
        CharSet = "UTF-8"
    };

    ulong ReqSize = 0;
    JsonReqMsg.TryComputeLength(out ReqSize);
    JsonReqMsg.Headers.ContentLength = ReqSize;

    var videoFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.mp4"));
    var prop = await videoFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status"));
    request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", prop.Size.ToString());
    request.Headers.Add("x-upload-content-type", "video/*");
    request.Content = JsonReqMsg;

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AuthToken.TokenType + " " + AuthToken.AccessToken);

    var UploadReq = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request);
    if (UploadReq.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string _VideoUrl = string.Empty;
        var res = await UploadReq.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        UploadReq.Headers.TryGetValue("Location", out _VideoUrl);

        var binaryContent = new HttpBufferContent(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(videoFile));
        var UploadReq_ = await httpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(_VideoUrl), binaryContent);
        if (UploadReq_.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var res_ = await UploadReq_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Error JSON

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API documentation has error in sample JSON request. `categoryId` value would be `string` not `int` & `embeddable` key has **True** as value. It should be `true`, without capital **T**.

Check out this also: [YouTube API Video Upload Parse Error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147390/youtube-api-video-upload-parse-error-in-c-sharp)